# how to properly use char and wchar_t in NativeCall (Perl6)

Tags: c, winapi, console-application, raku

I am calling `ReadConsoleInputW` from Kernel32.dll using `NativeCall`
A part of the struct I have to pass into that function looks like this

```
typedef struct _KEY_EVENT_RECORD {
    BOOL bKeyDown;
    WORD wRepeatCount;
    WORD wVirtualKeyCode;
    WORD wVirtualScanCode;
    union {
        WCHAR UnicodeChar;
        CHAR  AsciiChar;
    } uChar;
    DWORD dwControlKeyState;
}
```

which I have implemented as

```
class KEY_EVENT_RECORD_CHAR is repr('CUnion') {
    has uint16 $.UnicodeChar;
    has uint8  $.AsciiChar;
}   
class KEY_EVENT_RECORD is repr('CStruct') {
    has bool $.bKeyDown;
    has uint16 $.wRepeatCount;
    has uint16 $.wVirtualKeyCode;
    has uint16 $.wVirtualScanCode;
    HAS KEY_EVENT_RECORD_CHAR $.uChar;
    has uint32 $.dwControlKeyState;
}
```

My code works, in the sense that it doesn't crash. However, the values of the UnicodeChar and AsciiChar fields differ from the output of the C version of the program. For instance, if I type "a", the Perl version says the char is 30 (not 65 as I expect), whereas in C it's 65/"a".

I'm not a C-Guru but I don't see what's wrong there, I mean a char is one byte wide and a wchar_t is 2 bytes.

What am I missing?

Comment: 65 is "A" instead of "a". `ord` is used to convert a character to a number. So `ord("A")` will return 65. Can you have a try?

Comment: I would put `int32` instead of `bool` just in case the Perl maps it to something with size not equal 4. For test replace union with just `uint16` and see if anything changes. Check also `INPUT_RECORD` definition which embeds `KEY_EVENT_RECORD`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized when I look at the struct in the c debugger it thinks that boolean is an int, and sure enough BOOL is defined as int in the header file. I changed my class accordingly and now everything works. Thanks

Comment: In case people end up here looking for a way to use `wchar_t` with NativeCall, I have a [pullreq](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/3044) open to add support for `wchar_t`, `wint_t`, `char16_t`, and `char32_t` to Rakudo, nqp, and MoarVM so the backends can figure out what those types really are rather than having to guess in your own code (if it gets merged, at least).

Comment: Not really neccessary since those types are "frozen" for compatibility reasons.Under Windows a wchar_t is 2 bytes wide, regardless if it is on 32 bit or 64 bit or future 128 bit. ( I think )

Comment: This is the case on Windows, but on other platforms (like Solaris), the size of `wchar_t` does depend on what architecture you're using. Certain compiler flags can also make it harder to tell what its size is from Perl 6.